# OAuth2 INTRIDEA gem and HTTP basic authentication header

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api, ringcentral

Using INTRIDEA's OAuth2 Ruby gem, is there a recommended way to add the HTTP basic authentication header using the password strategy?

This approach is recommended by [IETF RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and required by the Yahoo and RingCentral OAuth 2.0 implementations.

The required header I'm working with is of the following format:

```
Authorization: Basic <base 64 encoded "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET">
```

The following doesn't work and doesn't seem to add the Authorization header:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET', :site => 'https://example.com)
token  = client.password.get_token('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
```

The following works, but is verbose:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET', :site => 'https://example.com)
token  = client.password.get_token('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', \
  :headers => { 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' + Base64.strict_encode64("CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET") \
)
```

The password strategy examples I've seen don't explicitly include the header so I'm wondering how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the docs for the `auth_code` strategy and [the code](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/) for `oauth2/strategy/password.rb`, `oauth2/strategy/base.rb` and `oauth2/client.rb`, it appears the OAuth2 gem will add the `client_id` and `client_secret` form parameters to the body but not the header. This is permitted but `NOT RECOMMENDED` by [IETF RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). To add the IETF recommended `Authorization` header, it appears you need to add it as parameter as shown above.

More info: [Pull request #192](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/pull/192) covers this but may be stalled due to backward compatibility issues.